# What does the .+ operator do in this code?

Tags: groovy

I'm new to groovy and I saw this code which is exactly what I need and works but I don't know why.

I have a string like this: `drink-all-of-the-water` where the words "all" and "water" will be swapped out for different words but the rest will remain the same and I want to save the optional strings into 2 separate variables.

For example:

```
drink-some-of-the-ginger-beer
var1 = some 
var2 = ginger-beer
```

Or:

```
drink-a-glass-of-the-orange-juice
var1 = a-glass
var2 = orange-juice
```

This works but I don't know how, could anyone explain? It's like it's saving whatever's in place of .+ in a nested list? Is that correct?

```
def myString = drink-a-glass-of-the-orange-juice
def getVars = myString =~ /drink-(.+)-of-the-(.+)/
def var1 = getVars[0][1]
def var2 = getVars[0][2]
```

var1 returns `a-glass` and var2 returns `orange-juice`

Comment: This looks like a regular expression that matches groups of 1 or many characters of virtually any kind.

Comment: It is not a special Groovy syntax, it is a standard regular expression which Groovy supports. The '.' means any character and '+' means one or more of them and the '()' is a selector. https://regex101.com/ is a great website for learning about and experimenting with regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes basically explaining, in your case getVars is receiving the matching result.

`getVars[0]` represents the entire match, and `getVars[0][1]` and `getVars[0][2]` access the values captured by the first and second capturing groups, respectively.

So the `(.+)` is a capturing group that matches one or more characters of any type (except for a newline). The `.` means **"any type"** and `+` quantifier means **"one or more"** The parentheses around `.+` make it a capturing group, which means the matched content will be captured and can be accessed later.

The [summary of regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) should be a good one for more info.

Comment: Definitely need to read up and get to grips with regular expressions. Thank you for such a clear explanation!